# How to Extract URL and add hyperlink from file uploaded in Microsoft form into Excel online by using Power automate

Tags: excel, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, power-automate, ms-forms

i have a simple form that have 4 question, that 3 questions need upload file (question 2 is Mandatory)
[image]

I try to create the flow to save the ms form data to excel online.

[image]

How to extract the URL only and make it to hyperlink?

below is my flow:
[image] [image]
[image][image]
Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a test for your reference:

Here is form
[image]

Here is excel:

[image]

Here is flow:

[image]

File1 return message:outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r7cc5c536c5ee45a6bfeb688a5ad2f89c'])

Use json to parse the information returned by file in the Form
Then an array will be generated, and then use First to get the first one in the array to avoid using apply to each：

```
first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r7cc5c536c5ee45a6bfeb688a5ad2f89c']))?['id']
```

The link obtained directly from the file information returned by the form can only be used by yourself. In order for this link to be a shared link, we can create a sharelink through [Create share link]

So we use first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r7cc5c536c5ee45a6bfeb688a5ad2f89c']))?['id'] and the last?['id'] This is to get the file ID in parsing

[image]

Create share links for other files in the same way

[image]

In order to display the link form in excel, we use concat to splice the excel formula to fill in the excel cell.

```
 concat('=HYPERLINK("',outputs('Create_share_link_for_file_1')?['body/WebUrl'],'"',',','"',first(json(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/r7cc5c536c5ee45a6bfeb688a5ad2f89c']))?['name'],'")')
```

[image]

Here is test result:
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, sample and test. 
May i know where can find  "create share link for file 1 or 2" as the icon of the flow has broken?

Comment: OneDrive for Business  -> create share link